# Microsoft Graph assign user license to user

Tags: json, powershell, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to assign license to user in Office365 like I would do with powershell

```
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName user@domain.com -AddLicenses licenseName
```

But the difference is that I'm trying to do it with Microsoft Graph.

My URL is following:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('user@domain.com')/

And my json is following:

```
    { "assignedLicenses": [
                            {
                                "skuId": "myID"
                            }
                      ]
}
```

But in response I'm getting following message:

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": "Request_BadRequest",
>           "message": "Property 'assignedLicenses' is read-only and cannot be set.",
>           "innerError": {
>               "request-id": "myID",
>               "date": "2016-03-31T09:07:34"
>           }
>       }
>   }

The question is how do I work around this issue and actually set license? Or there is no way yo work around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Support for Assigning User Licenses in Microsoft Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595973/support-for-assigning-user-licenses-in-microsoft-graph-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the solution [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscription_get)

---

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. But your answer points to Subscription GET.

Answer (score 0):

As the API has been updated since this question has been posted the following document should help answer the question.

[Assign License To User](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_assignlicense) MS Graph Api V1.0 docs